# Insets around section of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is there a way to give spacing around a section? I know this can be done using UICollectionView. Have implemented all the things using UITableView and UITableViewCells, don't want to move things to UICollectionView.

I am trying to achieve space around the section(all sides) to give a group kind of feel for section(including header, cells and footer views).

Comment: Please share the screenshot/image for better explanation.

Comment: @Kishoretheju what have you tried? can you post a screenshot of where you want spacing?

Comment: can you show the image or screenshot what you want to achieve..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straight forward api for this.

1. Add some space on every side of UI elements which you have added on top of section header view. eg. (10,10,width,height)
2. Apply same gap for Cell subviews as well.

Comment: Will move it to collectionview instead, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int)` and `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int)` to add more space between sections without messing with margins.

Comment: question is "Is there a way to give spacing around a section?"..... your answer is about giving space between section (only in  top and bottom)..

Answer (score 1):

If you created your table view section header via IB, you should add the one more UIView object before doing anything else. Then, you have to add correct constraints to this view relative to the header content view. I think you will add your margins from each side. Then you should adjust your table view background colour. Now I think you are free to make something like you described

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use the tableView **separator inset**, with the separator style of **none**, and That's it!
I know it's a bit late but hopefully the answer could be of use for others.

[image]
[image]